# Gradle - Which task creates the 'build' directory?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, findbugs, gradle-plugin

I'm using Android Studio 1.3.2 on Mac.

Gradle version is listed as 2.2.1, Android Plugin version 1.3.1.

I have applied the [FindBugs Gradle plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.FindBugs.html), and I've created a task that successfully runs the analysis on the directory 'build/intermediates/classes'.

To trigger this task on Gradle Sync, I've added it as a dependency to the `preBuild` task, like this:

```
preBuild.dependsOn findBugs
```

The problem with this dependency is that, at time of preBuild, the generated class files are either non-existent (first sync) or stale (remaining from previous sync). Basically, **I want my task to run immediately after the 'build/intermediates/classes' directory is created, or when the files there are refreshed as part of the 'Sync' operation**.

Looking at the tasks available, I can see the 'clean' task has the following description:

```
clean - Deletes the build directory.
```

However, none of the other tasks I see describe the directory's *creation*. My first thought was "Well, it's got to be the build task, right?". Unfortunately, as usual, it's not that simple (pressing gradle 'sync' button, does not trigger my task when I've added it as a dependency to the 'build' task). Is no such task available? If so, which task would best suit what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see all tasks using **./gradlew tasks**

The **build** task is the main one. It builds everything, generates APKs and runs all checks.

I recommend you adding the following to the build.gradle file:

```
check.dependsOn 'findbugs'
```

So when you run the **check** task, it will execute findbugs as well.

Then also set a dependency on findBugs for the compilation task:

```
task findbugs(type: FindBugs, dependsOn: 'compileDebugSources') {...}
```

This will compile the source in case you run findbugs without previously compiling it.

Comment: Even when adding my task as a dependency to build or check task, pressing the "gradle sync" button does not trigger my task. The only task I've found that does this, is preBuild. But that's too early, as the build/intermediates/classes directory has not been added or refreshed yet. And trying to add a dependency to the subsequent tasks gives me errors. I was hoping there was something I missed, but it's looking like I'll have to settle for triggering when "run" button is pressed instead. Probably makes more sense that way anyway. Thanks for the prompt response!

Comment: I recommend you try to run it from command line to check the difference. Android Studio configuration can be a little tricky sometimes, but command line should work.